# To calculate the limit :

Tags: analysis, limits, functions

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{n^2}(\arctan\frac{a}{n}-\arctan\frac{a}{n+1})$$
I used the formula $\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$,but it just doesn't work.
Waiting for your help...

Comment: First apply $\arctan a+\arctan b=\arctan \frac {a+b}{1-ab}$. Also, here $a,b$ are small, therefore we can assume, $ab$ is less than $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  Shubham' suggestion, apply $$\arctan x+\arctan y=\arctan \frac {x+y}{1-xy}$$ with $x=\frac{a}{n}$ and $y=-\frac{a}{n+1}$. You then arrive to $$\arctan\frac an-\arctan\frac a{n+1}=\arctan\frac {a} {n(n+1)+a^2}$$ Now, use the fact that, close to zero, $\arctan (x)=x+O\left(x^3\right)$ and replace $x$ by $\frac {a} {n(n+1)+a^2}$. So, $${n^2}(\arctan\frac{a}{n}-\arctan\frac{a}{n+1}) \simeq \frac {n^2 a} {n(n+1)+a^2}$$ I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: It's very kind of you!

Comment: You are very welcome !

Answer (score 1):

Use the mean value theorem:
$$
\arctan\frac an-\arctan\frac a{n+1}=\Bigl(\frac an-\frac a{n+1}\Bigr)\frac{1}{1+c_n^2}
$$
with
$$
\frac a{n+1}<c_n<\frac a{n}.
$$

Comment: That's great!Thx a lot!!!

Comment: Professor,I prefer your answer,but please excuse me... the 72-year-old grandpa is too admirable